# How to edit and update xml file with Swift

Tags: swift, xml

I'm trying to merge two xml files to a new xml file. Also adding one line `<xxxxxxxxxxXML Seperatorxxxxxxxxxx>` in between two xml.

I'm using SWXMLHash pod to parser my xml file. I already have two var of xml that I need to merge. Thanks!

```
var oldXML: XMLIndexer?
var newXML: XMLIndexer?
var combinedXML: XMLIndexer?

func mergeEHR(oldXML: XMLIndexer, newXML: XMLIndexer) -> XMLIndexer {
        do {

            /// Don't know how to merge it.

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
 }
```

I want it to be

```
var combinedXML = 

<oldXML>
...
</oldXML>
xxxxxxxxxxXML Seperatorxxxxxxxxxx
<newXML>
 ...
</newXML>
```

Comment: But then it won’t be proper xml any longer so why bother with an xml parser? Treat them as 2 ordinary text files instead when merging them.

Comment: I'm working with server and if there's a way to just do xml instead of convert to string why not? I don't know if you are the one down vote my question but I'm here to learn so I ask question. I looked up different sites and questions cant find the answer.

Comment: @PanLin There is no need to treat them as XML or convert them to strings. Create a new file. Copy the contents, as-is, of the first file to the new file. Write the separator to the new file. Then copy the contents, as-is, of the second file to the new file. Done. No need parse anything.

Comment: No I didn't down vote and I don't understand how that is relevant to my comment but  I would like to add that it might not even be possible to treat them as xml since the final result isn't xml but that of course depends on if/how the parser does any validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since combined `XML` will be **not a valid `XML`** (even if it was, doesn't matter), treat them as a raw `String`:

```
let oldXMLString = try! String(contentsOfFile: <#PathToOldXML#>) // If it is on the file, else assign it the way it should
let separator = "<xxxxxxxxxxXML Seperatorxxxxxxxxxx>"
let newXMLString = try! String(contentsOfFile: <#PathToNewXML#>) // If it is on the file, else assign it the way it should

let combinedXMLString = [oldXMLString, separator, newXMLString].joined(separator: "\n")
try! combinedXMLString.write(toFile: <#PathToDestinationOfTheCombinedXML#>, atomically: <#Bool#>, encoding: <#String.Encoding#>)
```

Then you can treat the result as an *invalid* `XML` or etc. again.